How to dynamically add form fields(check box and radio button) to Word using openxml c#?
I use OpenXml to convert my html into word doc but html form fields (input type radio and check boxes) are not getting converted to word so I decided to add these fields explicitly to word while converting html. Can anyone provide sample code or guide me please?
